# Is "at a time" correct?

Tags: phrase-requests, writing

I would like to find a way to express the meaning of "at some time". For example:

> I think everyone has his study or working rhythm **at a time**. This rhythm varies for different person, and may be different **at a different time** for the same person. Especially it can
>   change over time as he becomes more experienced. So pacing them at a pre-fixed pace may not work well.

**At a time** sounds awkward to me. What do you think?

Comment: @JasperLoy: at a particular time he has a particular rhythm that works best for him

Comment: Let me use a metaphor: frequency of vibration.

Comment: Is this a passage somewhere that you read? Or are you composing this yourself?

Comment: @Mitch: It is mine words. How bad is it?

Comment: @Time: I was just wondering the direction of the question, reading or composition. Others have addressed how good it sounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right; it is awkward.  I would use *at any given time*:

> I think everyone has his own study or working rhythm **at any given time**. This rhythm varies between different people, and may be different **at different times** for the same person.

I changed *at a different time* to the plural, since the rhythm can't be different at a single time.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to read something like

> I think everyone has a study or working rhythm. This rhythm varies
>   between different people, and may be different at different times for
>   the same person. In particular, it can increase over time as
>   individuals become more experienced. So pacing everyone at the same
>   pre-fixed rate may not work well.

Comment: Thanks! If not considering the example, do you have a better idea to say "at a time"?

Comment: Sometimes "at a particular time" may be better than "at a time".  It all depends on the context.  "The animals entered the ark two at a time" works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In principle "at a time" would work, but the phrase "*n* at a time" (meaning "in groups of *n* items") is so prevalent that it interferes with interpreting the phrase in another way: my reaction on reading your sentence is first to be confused, and then a moment later to go "Oh, I see, that's what it means".

As soon as you put a qualifying word (such as "particular", or "any given", as suggested in other answers) this rules out the other meaning and it becomes clear.